# Is website visited by search engines?

Tags: seo, google, search-engines, ranking

How can I find out that my website which is actually uploaded on webhosting for about two months is visited by search engines like google, yahoo and others? Which ranking sites should I regularly check to see how my web is in according to other websites?

Answer (score 3):

> How can I find out that my website which is actually uploaded on webhosting for about two months is visited by search engines like google, yahoo and others?

Check your logs or site statistics like [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) if you installed it, or [Awstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) if your host provides it.

> Which ranking sites should I regularly check to see how my web is in according to other websites?

Use [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) for this

Answer (score 2):

Usually in your logs or in the analysis programs, the search engine bots typically have unique browser types, so for example, instead of seeing Firefox, IE, Chrome, etc.  you might see:  GoogleBot, Slurp (Yahoo's old algorithm), Bing, etc.   Usually you also can tell bots from humans because the visitor IP's for bots will likely have hundreds if not thousands of page downloads/hits vs. human visitors which might do 5 or so (depending on the site of course).

That information however is just ballpark blanket info. Your analytics program will likely have much more options to sift the data, but usually the tips above will help with all programs.

Also as John mentioned, Awstats and Google Analytics are definitely great programs to use, and Awstats will likely be setup by default if you're running your site on cPanel (which is a common admin system).

As for rankings, you will want to have a look at Technorati, and Alexa although HubSpot.com (a marketing company) offers an excellent comparison tool to see how your site compares to competitors. In addition the tools at SEOMoz.com are excellent for measuring performance.

Answer (score 0):

Besides Google Webmaster Tools, you could check [Bing Webmaster Tools](http://www.bing.com/toolbox/webmaster/) to know which of your pages Bing has indexed or "is visited by" Bing. [Now that Bing Webmaster Tools has fully integrated in Yahoo’s traffic numbers as well](http://searchengineland.com/bing-webmaster-tools-integrates-yahoo-traffic-data-90585), with both these tools you have all the 3 major search engines covered.